# Is it possible to use Azure AD or Azure B2C Authentication with Microsoft Flow?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, power-automate

I am creating flows in Microsoft Flow using the Swagger file generated for my API. I see that there is a setting called Identity Provider with an option called "Azure Active Directory". Can I use this to authenticate the flow with Azure B2C? Or at last with Azure AD?

PS: I have tried with Azure AD but get an error: his connection is not authenticated. Verify Password.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, if you were developing an custom connectors implement by your own web API and want to protect it via Azure AD, it is possible. However, AFAIK, it doesn't support protecting with Azure AD B2C since we need to append the policy for the authorization/token request(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code)), however the Swagger doesn't support to add the custom parameter for the oAuth2 authentication(refer [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityDefinitionsObject)).

Based on the error message, it seems that you didn't provide the correct password. If I misunderstood, would you minding share the request url you login?

In-addition, Here is an helpful article about to setup the connect using Azure AD authentication:

[Register and use custom connectors in Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/register-custom-api/)

And to protect the web API using Azure AD, you can refer the document below:

[Help protect a web API by using bearer tokens from Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet)

Comment: It seems that B2C policy now supports "request", can you check and confirm with latest documentation on link you provided?